# Jimdo: Create rotating clipped disk on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a rotating CD/Disk effect when the play button is clicked. I managed to come up with an example, see the code below. This is partially the state of the player when it is in play mode.

What I would like to create is have a square image with a play button on top. When the user clicks the button, the pause button appears and the middle part of the image starts rotating like a spinning CD/Disk.

I have tried a few things but my skills in JavaScript are lacking to create such an effect.

Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** The code answer should be able to work on the [Jimdo](https://www.jimdo.com/) site builder.

```js
$(function() {
  var activePlayerStartBtn;

  function stopOtherPlayerSetNewAsActive(element) {
    var toShow = $(element).parent().find('.btn.hide')[0];
    $(element).addClass('hide');
    $(toShow).removeClass('hide');

    if (activePlayerStartBtn) {
      var stopButton = $(activePlayerStartBtn).parent().find('.btn').not('.hide')[0];
      $(stopButton).addClass('hide');
      $(activePlayerStartBtn).removeClass('hide');
    }

    activePlayerStartBtn = element;
  }

  function stopPlayer(element) {
    $(element).addClass('hide');
    $(activePlayerStartBtn).removeClass('hide');
    activePlayerStartBtn = null;
  }

  var widget1 = SC.Widget("so");
  $("#playSound").click(function() {
    widget1.play();
    stopOtherPlayerSetNewAsActive("#playSound");
  });
  $("#stopSound").click(function() {
    widget1.pause();
    stopPlayer('#stopSound');
  });
});
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.img-circle {
  clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
  animation: loading 10s linear infinite;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-50%, -53%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: .7;
  clip-path: circle(33% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(33% at 50% 50%);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/js/api.js">
</script>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000281899403-n7tdjo-t500x500.jpg" alt="img" class="img-circle">
  <img id="playSound" src="https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/sc-playbtn.svg" alt="play" title="play" class="btn" name="playSound">
  <img id="stopSound" src="https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/sc-pausebtn.svg" alt="pause" title="pause" class="btn hide" name="stopSound">
</div>

<iframe id="so" width="0%" height="0" scrolling="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/380167502&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=false"
  frameborder="0" name="so" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

### [jsFiddle with rotating Disk example](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/u0j538w4)

Let me explain what is happening so you understand what the code and styles do.

I've added the album image twice, one is the background, one is used to create the rotating disk. It looks like this.

```
<img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000281899403-n7tdjo-t500x500.jpg" alt="img" class="img-circle -clipped">
<img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000281899403-n7tdjo-t500x500.jpg" alt="img" class="img-circle">
```

You don't see the clipped image, it only is noticed when the animation starts.

When a player is clicked, the `-rotating` class is added to start the animation.

```
// Find the clippedImg and add the class -rotating to start the  animation
var clippedImg = $(element).parent().find('.-clipped')[0];
$(clippedImg).addClass('-rotating');
```

When the pause button is clicked, the `-rotating` class is removed.

Let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to utilize the css property `animation-play-state: paused;`

```js
$(function() {
  var activePlayerStartBtn;

  function stopOtherPlayerSetNewAsActive(element) {
    var toShow = $(element).parent().find('.btn.hide')[0];
    $(element).addClass('hide');
    $(toShow).removeClass('hide');
    $('.img-circle').removeClass('paused');

    if (activePlayerStartBtn) {
      var stopButton = $(activePlayerStartBtn).parent().find('.btn').not('.hide')[0];
      $(stopButton).addClass('hide');
      $(activePlayerStartBtn).removeClass('hide');
    }

    activePlayerStartBtn = element;
  }

  function stopPlayer(element) {
    $(element).addClass('hide');
    $(activePlayerStartBtn).removeClass('hide');
    $('.img-circle').addClass('paused');
    activePlayerStartBtn = null;
  }

  var widget1 = SC.Widget("so");
  $("#playSound").click(function() {
    widget1.play();
    stopOtherPlayerSetNewAsActive("#playSound");
  });
  $("#stopSound").click(function() {
    widget1.pause();
    stopPlayer('#stopSound');
  });
});
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.img-circle {
  clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%);
  animation: loading 10s linear infinite;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-50%, -53%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: .7;
  clip-path: circle(33% at 50% 50%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(33% at 50% 50%);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/js/api.js">
</script>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000281899403-n7tdjo-t500x500.jpg" alt="img" class="img-circle paused">
  <img id="playSound" src="https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/sc-playbtn.svg" alt="play" title="play" class="btn" name="playSound">
  <img id="stopSound" src="https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/sc-pausebtn.svg" alt="pause" title="pause" class="btn hide" name="stopSound">
</div>

<iframe id="so" width="0%" height="0" scrolling="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/380167502&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=false"
  frameborder="0" name="so" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```